# Qt Stylesheet using property enum

Tags: python, pyside, qtstylesheets

I'm attempting to use the enum value of a QAbstractSpinBox property to style it differently, however it doesn't appear to work when following the directions of the docs. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#ButtonSymbols-enum

When the user sets the button style to use the plusMinus i want to change the style to something else. Why doesn't this work?

```
QAbstractSpinBox[buttonSymbols="1"]::down-button {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) is reviewed:

[image]

So you should not use the "1" but the name of the enum:

```css
QAbstractSpinBox[buttonSymbols="PlusMinus"]::down-button {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Sadly that does not work in Pyside using python 2.7